# Two A/C clutch diodes?

Tags: electrical, ac, wiring, cobalt, wiring-diagram

'07 Cobalt.  A/C clutch fuse was blown.  The clutch circuit now reads open to ground, so it seems something catastrophic happened.  I am considering what a repair would involve.

The schematic (below) shows two clamp diodes for the clutch coil - one internal to the clutch, the other in the fuse block.  Meter-testing the circuit with polarity reversed also reads open, indicating that the diode(s) are non-conducting.  So, it/they would need replacement.

The problem is, I find no diode on the fuse block.  IDK why there should be two diodes anyway, so I wonder if this might be an error in the schematic - maybe a cut/paste from an older design, where the (single) diode *was* in the fuse block.  In support of this, GM once had a [plug-in diode](https://www.gmpartsdirect.com/oem-parts/gm-multi-function-diode-12135037) that looks designed to fit fuse block type connectors.

So, my question: is there really supposed to be a diode in the fuse block?

[image: OEM schematic, fr Alldata]

Comment: Maybe an optional diode in the fuse box allows the use of a compressor that doesn’t have a built in diode.

Comment: When you tested the continuity of the diode, did you have the multimeter set to the diode testing setting?

Comment: Did you test continuity directly across A and B on the compressor clutch?

Comment: @HandyHowie - (a) I could buy the 'optional diode' theory, if I found a place for the diode in the fuse box.  But, I don't.  (b) yes, diode setting.  (c) no; it looks like the fender liner has to come off to get at the connector (or anything else on the compressor).  I'm avoiding doing that.

Comment: Interesting that the 2008 version doesn't have the diode in the clutch https://ww2-secure.justanswer.com/uploads/BM/bmaxwell8686/2014-06-13_002034_printing_from_ondemand5-page-001.jpg

Comment: @HandyHowie - Yeah, interesting.  OTOH, the layout pix I find for the '08 fuse block don't show a diode, and I don't find it listed as a replacement part for the '08.  I did find a layout of an '05 Colorado that does show a diode.  It looks like I don't have one, and so I don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to keep this from popping up in the future ...

- It looks like some GM makes/models/years did have a clamp diode in the fuse block.  I'd guess that's why it shows in my schematic.
- If there was a diode in the fuse block, it appears it would plug in like fuse.  There isn't any such in this car, so I don't have one - the only clamp diode is the one (presumably) across the clutch coil.

End of story.